# C++ abstract user interface design

Tags: c++, oop, model-view-controller, user-interface

I am writing a cross-platform UI toolkit for a variety of targets, some of which are embedded. Some of these platforms support a "retained" rendering mode, and some of them are more "immediate", so I am thinking that for my visuals I have two trees - pseudocode:

```
abstract class Visual 
{
    Visual( Widget widget ) { this.widget = widget; }
}

abstract class RetainedVisual : Visual
{
    abstract void Setup( Renderer r );
    abstract void Teardown( Renderer r );
}

abstract class ImmediateVisual : Visual
{
    abstract void Paint( Renderer r );
}
```

So far so good. But now I also have `ContainerVisual` classes which encode the widget hierarchy:

```
abstract class ContainerVisual : Visual
{
    void AddChild( Visual child ) {}
}
```

which sort of forces me into having an `ImmediateContainerVisual` and a `RetainedContainerVisual` classes which is starting to look bloated. Ideas for a better design?

Comment: Hence the word "pseudocode", Joachim. The end design must be implementable in C++ (so: no reflection or other cunning stuff).

Comment: Does _retained_ mean buffered? Also, you haven't said what the functional difference between `RetainedVisual` and `ImmediateVisual` is supposed to be, or what they have in common (they share a base class but apparently no virtual methods or data).

Comment: "Retained" means you submit graphics to a context and then forget about them (until something changes). So "Setup" pushes the graphics once into the renderer. and "Teardown" removes them.

"Immediate" means you continually paint the graphics once every frame into the renderer. You don't need to invalidate stuff because it generally all gets redrawn anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Best alternative is to combine the 3 classes to same Visual class:

```
class Visual {
   Visual(Widget w);
   bool SupportsSetupTearDown();
   bool SupportsPaint();
   abstract void Setup(Renderer r);
   abstract void TearDown(Renderer r);
   abstract void Paint(Renderer r);
};
```

Then there wont be any problems with container widgets. All visuals should implement both methods of rendering, and when the target changes, the system will start calling different functions. This also allows conditionally not implement one way, and special visuals could be built which convert from SetupTearDown to Paint and from Paint to SetupTearDown.

Comment: Thanks - this is sort of the way I was heading, but I feel a bit uncomfortable about these "kitchen sink" interfaces, they don't seem very OO. On the other hand, class bloat doesn't seem very good either. Rocks and Hard Places.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to decide what way to go without having more information: What's the difference between Retained/Immediate in terms of functionality? What does a Container do?

But nevertheless, in C++ you might consider to use a class template for things like Container:

```
template <typename BaseType>
class ContainerVisual : public BaseType
{
public:
    void AddChild(BaseType & /*or smart pointer or whatever*/ child ) {}
}
```

Comment: In retained mode, you call Setup(Renderer r) to draw your graphics, and Teardown(Renderer r) to remove them. The framework handles refreshes and repaints because it caches where all the primitives are and what they look like. In immediate mode, you call Paint(Renderer r) every frame - it's lower level, often involving just pushing pixels to a frame buffer, with no concept of primitives. You don't worry about invalidating because you always repaint, essentially.

Comment: Container widgets contain child widgets, and so must propagate the correct interface to the children.